# UpdateSelectInput does not have a multiple = TRUE function

Tags: r, shiny

I just want to check if anyone else has run into this problem in Shiny. It seems the UpdateSelectInput funcionality cannot take the argument: multiple = TRUE.

I tried the following in rmarkdown (Factornames() is a reactive variable):

```
updateSelectInput(session = session, inputId = "Columns",
                    choices = isolate(Factornames()),
                    selected = isolate(Factornames())[1:3], multiple = T)
```

When I try to update it it gives me an error when I have the same input:

```
updateSelectInput: unused argument (multiple = T)
```

It works perfectly when I do not add multiple = T, but then it only uses the inputs [1:3] and cannot accept anything else.

Apologies for not having a full MWE, but this is more a functional question (i.e. whether the option exists or can be worked around).

Comment: If that's indeed true (which I assume it is), this sounds like something you should tell the shiny developers but opening an issue on GitHub.  StackOverflow can't help much with that

Comment: Sure. Just thought someone here might have solved the issue. For someone with a similar problem stumbling upon this, I opened an issue here: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1192.